# GIN index not used when adding order clause

Tags: postgresql, index, full-text-search

I'm trying to speed up a query that executes three `ILIKE` queries and reduces these with or (returning the overall count and 10 entries)

```sql
SELECT  *, count(*) OVER() as filtered_count FROM "users" 
WHERE (
   (f_unaccent("users"."first_name") ILIKE f_unaccent('%foo%') OR 
    f_unaccent("users"."last_name") ILIKE f_unaccent('%foo%')) OR 
    f_unaccent("users"."club_or_hometown") ILIKE f_unaccent('%foo%')
) LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
```

This works reasonably fast after adding gin-indexes for all queried attributes (here only for first_name):

```
CREATE INDEX users_first_name_gin
ON users
USING gin
(f_unaccent(first_name::text) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" gin_trgm_ops);
```

If I however add an additional order clause, e. g. `ORDER BY users.first_name ASC`, postgresql does not use the gin index, but the normal b-tree index on `first_name`, then filters the result. This takes significantly longer in my application. How can I adapt the query/indexes to keep using the gin indexes even for ordered queries?

edit: I'm using postgresql 9.4

Explain of unordered query:

```
"Limit  (cost=125.98..139.61 rows=10 width=58) (actual time=17.828..17.833 rows=10 loops=1)"
"  ->  WindowAgg  (cost=125.98..2972.72 rows=2088 width=58) (actual time=17.826..17.831 rows=10 loops=1)"
"        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on users (cost=125.98..2946.62 rows=2088 width=58) (actual time=0.915..16.816 rows=1755 loops=1)"
"              Recheck Cond: ((f_unaccent((first_name)::text) ~~* '%foo%'::text) OR (f_unaccent((last_name)::text) ~~* '%foo%'::text) OR (f_unaccent((club_or_hometown)::text) ~~* '%foo%'::text))"
"              Heap Blocks: exact=891"
"              ->  BitmapOr  (cost=125.98..125.98 rows=2088 width=0) (actual time=0.742..0.742 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on users_first_name_gin  (cost=0.00..51.80 rows=2074 width=0) (actual time=0.600..0.600 rows=1735 loops=1)"
"                          Index Cond: (f_unaccent((first_name)::text) ~~* '%foo%'::text)"
"                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on users_last_name_gin  (cost=0.00..36.31 rows=8 width=0) (actual time=0.069..0.069 rows=20 loops=1)"
"                          Index Cond: (f_unaccent((last_name)::text) ~~* '%foo%'::text)"
"                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on users_club_or_hometown_gin  (cost=0.00..36.29 rows=6 width=0) (actual time=0.072..0.072 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                          Index Cond: (f_unaccent((club_or_hometown)::text) ~~* '%foo%'::text)"
"Planning time: 0.791 ms"
"Execution time: 17.909 ms"
```

Explain of ordered query:

```
"Limit  (cost=0.42..404.22 rows=10 width=58) (actual time=2363.902..2363.908 rows=10 loops=1)"
"  ->  WindowAgg  (cost=0.42..84314.74 rows=2088 width=58) (actual time=2363.900..2363.904 rows=10 loops=1)"
"        ->  Index Scan using index_users_on_first_name on users  (cost=0.42..84288.64 rows=2088 width=58) (actual time=132.873..2362.996 rows=1755 loops=1)"
"              Filter: ((f_unaccent((first_name)::text) ~~* '%foo%'::text) OR (f_unaccent((last_name)::text) ~~* '%foo%'::text) OR (f_unaccent((club_or_hometown)::text) ~~* '%foo%'::text))"
"              Rows Removed by Filter: 99646"
"Planning time: 0.937 ms"
"Execution time: 2363.989 ms"
```

The indexes from `\d users`

```
"users_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
"index_users_on_club_or_hometown" btree (club_or_hometown)
"index_users_on_first_name" btree (first_name)
"index_users_on_last_name" btree (last_name)
"users_club_or_hometown_gin" gin (f_unaccent(club_or_hometown::text) gin_trgm_ops)
"users_first_name_gin" gin (f_unaccent(first_name::text) gin_trgm_ops)
"users_last_name_gin" gin (f_unaccent(last_name::text) gin_trgm_ops)
```

edit2:

When disabling index scans with `set enable_indexscan = off;`, postgres uses the correct indexes again:

```
"Limit  (cost=3273.20..3273.22 rows=10 width=58) (actual time=32.231..32.231 rows=10 loops=1)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=3273.20..3279.30 rows=2442 width=58) (actual time=32.229..32.229 rows=10 loops=1)"
"        Sort Key: first_name"
"        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 26kB"
"        ->  WindowAgg  (cost=128.90..3220.43 rows=2442 width=58) (actual time=29.982..30.735 rows=2655 loops=1)"
"              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on users  (cost=128.90..3189.90 rows=2442 width=58) (actual time=1.323..28.260 rows=2655 loops=1)"
"                    Recheck Cond: ((f_unaccent((first_name)::text) ~~* '%foo%'::text) OR (f_unaccent((last_name)::text) ~~* '%foo%'::text) OR (f_unaccent((club_or_hometown)::text) ~~* '%foo%'::text))"
"                    Heap Blocks: exact=1057"
"                    ->  BitmapOr  (cost=128.90..128.90 rows=2443 width=0) (actual time=1.099..1.099 rows=0 loops=1)"
"                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on users_first_name_gin  (cost=0.00..54.46 rows=2428 width=0) (actual time=0.961..0.961 rows=2647 loops=1)"
"                                Index Cond: (f_unaccent((first_name)::text) ~~* '%foo%'::text)"
"                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on users_last_name_gin  (cost=0.00..36.31 rows=8 width=0) (actual time=0.066..0.066 rows=7 loops=1)"
"                                Index Cond: (f_unaccent((last_name)::text) ~~* '%foo%'::text)"
"                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on users_club_or_hometown_gin  (cost=0.00..36.29 rows=6 width=0) (actual time=0.071..0.071 rows=1 loops=1)"
"                                Index Cond: (f_unaccent((club_or_hometown)::text) ~~* '%foo%'::text)"
"Planning time: 0.803 ms"
"Execution time: 32.292 ms"
```

Comment: I further found out that the inefficient index is only used if the search query (`foo` in my example) appears in pg_stats.most_common_vals for this column. So I assume this skews the estimated costs into the wrong direction. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Can you add one more explain output for the second query with `ORDER BY` after disabling index scans temporarily in your session (`set enable_indexscan = off;`) The alternative plan using your GIN indexes might not be faster if the search term is very common, because all matching rows have to be retrieved and sorted. Also: how many rows in your table and what's the mean row width (roughly)? You could use this: `SELECT avg(s)::int FROM (SELECT pg_column_size(u) AS s FROM users u LIMIT 100) sub`. And: Do you *always* search all three columns for a match?

Comment: See my edits. It indeed only shows this behavior if the search query is one that often occurs in my database, which I checked in `pg_stats`. Yes, I'm always searching all three columns.

Comment: Did you tune [cost settings in postgresql.conf](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-query.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-QUERY-CONSTANTS)? In particular: `random_page_cost`, `cpu_index_tuple_cost` and `effective_cache_size`.  And how many rows total in your table?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your added comment is on the right track already:

> I further found out that the inefficient index is only used if the
> search query (foo in my example) appears in `pg_stats.most_common_vals`
> for this column. So I assume this skews the estimated costs into the
> wrong direction. Any ideas how to fix this?

If 'foo' is very common, Postgres expects it to be faster to just read from the b-tree index sequentially and just skip rows that do not match. The estimation is also based on cost setting and the expected selectivity of predicates. There are multiple entry points for skewed estimates.

- row counts in column statistics
- selectivity estimates for predicates
- Combined statistics for multiple predicates
- cost settings

#### Selectivity of predicates and combinations

Your most important problem seems to be here:

> (cost=0.42..84,314.74 **rows=2,088** width=58) (actual
> time=2,363.900..2,363.904 **rows=10** loops=1)

Postgres expects **209 times** as many rows as returned. explain.depesz.com can help auditing a query plan:  http://explain.depesz.com/s/53E

You may get more accurate estimates by increasing the statistics target for the indexed columns. Postgres not only gathers statistics for table columns, it does the same for indexed expressions (not for plain index columns for which statistics are available already). See:

- [Index that is not used, yet influences query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72649/index-that-is-not-used-yet-influences-query/72662)

You can check with:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stats WHERE tablename = 'users_first_name_gin';
```

Basic row counts and settings are in `pg_class` and `pg_attribute`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   pg_attribute
WHERE  attrelid = 'users_last_name_gin'::regclass;

SELECT *
FROM   pg_class
WHERE  oid = 'users_last_name_gin'::regclass;
```

Indexes are treated as special tables internally. This should make it less surprising that you can do use `ALTER TABLE` on an index:

```
ALTER TABLE users_last_name_gin
ALTER COLUMN f_unaccent SET STATISTICS 1000;
```

Use this to increase the sample size for calculating statistics for the index column. Then run `ANALYZE users` to update statistics.

You can't provide explicit column names for index entries, names are chosen automatically. You can look it up with the query on `pg_attribute` above. The column name `f_unaccent` is derived from the used function name.

Default [statistics target](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) is 100, the allowed range is 0 - 10000. For big tables with uneven data distribution, 100 is often not enough to get reasonable estimates. Set it to 1000 (example) for the index expression to get better estimates.

#### Workaround

Like [dezso commented](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/113132/gin-index-not-used-when-adding-order-clause#comment206725_113141) you can get the alternative query plan by encapsulating the original form in a CTE (which acts as optimization barrier in Postgres) - before `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` in the outer `SELECT`:

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT *, count(*) OVER() AS filtered_count
   FROM   users 
   WHERE (f_unaccent("users"."first_name")       ILIKE f_unaccent('%foo%') OR 
          f_unaccent("users"."last_name")        ILIKE f_unaccent('%foo%') OR 
          f_unaccent("users"."club_or_hometown") ILIKE f_unaccent('%foo%'))
   )
SELECT *
FROM   cte
ORDER  BY first_name
LIMIT  10;
```

#### Alternative index

You commented:

> I'm always searching all three columns

A single index for all three would be cheaper. GIN indexes can be multicolumn indexes. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-multicolumn.html)

> Currently, only the B-tree, GiST, GIN, and BRIN index types support
> multiple-key-column indexes.

And:

> A multicolumn GIN index can be used with query conditions that involve
> any subset of the index's columns. Unlike B-tree or GiST, index search
> effectiveness is the same regardless of which index column(s) the
> query conditions use.

So:

```
CREATE INDEX big_unaccent_big_gin_idx ON users USING gin (
     f_unaccent(first_name)       gin_trgm_ops
   , f_unaccent(last_name)        gin_trgm_ops
   , f_unaccent(club_or_hometown) gin_trgm_ops);
```

Reduces the triple overhead per index entry to just one. Should be faster overall. Or, faster yet, concatenate all three columns into a single string. I am adding a space as separator to avoid false positives. Use any character as separator that is not going to show up in search expressions:

```
CREATE INDEX big_unaccent_big_gin_idx ON users USING gin (
   f_unaccent(f_concat_ws(' ', first_name, last_name, club_or_hometown)) gin_trgm_ops);
```

Uses the custom function `f_concat_ws()`, which must be created first as explained here:

- [PostgreSQL full text search on many columns](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/164000/postgresql-full-text-search-on-many-columns/164081#164081)

If all columns are `NOT NULL`, you can use plain concatenation instead:

```
first_name || ' ' || last_name || ' ' || club_or_hometown
```

Be sure to use the *same expression* in your query:

```
WHERE f_unaccent(f_concat_ws(' ', first_name, last_name, club_or_hometown)) ILIKE '%foo%'
```

Set `STATISTICS` to 1000 or more like demonstrated above and `ANALYZE` before you test again. Be sure to run the query multiple times to compare warm cache to warm cache.

Besides the smaller index and faster computation, the main benefit for your case could be that a **single predicate is less susceptible to errors in the cost estimation**. Combining multiple predicates adds errors to the calculation.

Update: since Postgres 12, [multivariate statistics](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createstatistics.html) are available.

#### Force query plan

If all else fails, you can force your preferred query plan like I suggested in the comment by disabling index scans temporarily. Remember, this is an **evil hack** that may backfire if underlying data distribution changes or if you upgrade to the next Postgres version:

Use `SET LOCAL` to confine the effect to the transaction and wrap the whole thing in an explicit transaction.

```
BEGIN;
SET LOCAL enable_indexscan = off;
SELECT  ...  -- your query here
COMMIT;
```

Comment: I played round with the `SET STATISTICS` command before, but to no avail. Since I don't really want to use an evil hack/dirty workaround, I tried the concatenated index you suggested. That worked really well and even improved the speed of my queries. Thanks for your great suggestions!

Comment: Forcing query plan is no longer necessary with postgres 10.6.

Answer (score 0):

`ORDER BY` takes maximum precedence for indexes, and only (normally) quickly works with B-Tree.  Try to `ORDER BY f_unaccent`, this may potentially work.

Here is more information on this in the documentation :
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/indexes-ordering.html

> In addition to simply finding the rows to be returned by a query, an index may be able to deliver them in a specific sorted order. This allows a query's ORDER BY specification to be honored without a separate sorting step. Of the index types currently supported by PostgreSQL, only B-tree can produce sorted output — the other index types return matching rows in an unspecified, implementation-dependent order.

Comment: But this only works because the index for `f_unaccent(whatever_attribute)` does not exist. Is there no way to make postgresql do the sorting last, like it did before I added the b-tree index for `whatever_attribute`?

Comment: @panmari You can try to collect the matching rows first in a CTE (aka. `WITH` query) and do the `ORDER BY` on it, in the main `SELCT` clause.  As CTEs behave like an optimization fence, this should use the GIN indexes.