# Improve performance of query with many joins

Tags: postgresql, index, index-tuning, performance, postgresql-performance

From the following explain plan:

```
explain SELECT imei, cliente_avl_equipo.id_cliente AS idcliente,
               cliente_avl_vehiculo.grupo AS grupo, avl_vehiculo.id,
               avl_vehiculo.id_clase, avl_vehiculo_clase.icono AS icono,
               avl_vehiculo.descripcion, avl_vehiculo.patente,
               avl_vehiculo.info, avl_vehiculo.conductor,
               avl_vehiculo.fijo_chasis, avl_vehiculo.enabled
        FROM   cliente_avl_vehiculo,avl_vehiculo, avl_vehiculo_equipo,
               cliente_avl_equipo, avl_vehiculo_clase
        WHERE  avl_vehiculo.id                 =avl_vehiculo_equipo.id
        AND    cliente_avl_vehiculo.vehiculo_id=avl_vehiculo.id
        AND    cliente_avl_equipo.imei_equipo  =avl_vehiculo_equipo.imei
        AND    avl_vehiculo_clase.id           =avl_vehiculo.id_clase
        AND    avl_vehiculo_equipo.imei        =1234
```

I get an output like this:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..22.57 rows=1 width=125
    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..22.29 rows=1 width=67)
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..14.92 rows=1 width=63)
          ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..14.58 rows=1 width=63)
                ->  Index Scan using fki_avl_vehiculo_equipo_imei on avl_vehiculo_equipo  (cost=0.00..7.28 rows=1 width=12)
                      Index Cond: (imei = 1234)
                ->  Index Scan using index_avl_vehiculo_id on avl_vehiculo  (cost=0.00..7.29 rows=1 width=51)
                      Index Cond: (id = avl_vehiculo_equipo.id)
          ->  Index Scan using index_cliente_avl_vehiculo_id on cliente_avl_vehiculo  (cost=0.00..0.33 rows=1 width=8)
               Index Cond: (vehiculo_id = avl_vehiculo.id)
       ->  Index Scan using fki_cliente_avl_equipo_imei on cliente_avl_equipo  (cost=0.00..7.36 rows=1 width=12)
              Index Cond: (imei_equipo = 1234)
    ->  Index Scan using index_avl_vehiculo_clase_id on avl_vehiculo_clase  (cost=0.00..0.27 rows=1 width=62)
        Index Cond: (id = avl_vehiculo.id_clase)
```

I'm not too familiar with explain outputs, but the `Index Scan` lines seem OK to me, but I'm in doubt with the `Nested Loop` ones, any advise would be appreciated.

Added output of `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers)` as requested by @a_horse_with_no_name:

```
Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..22.57 rows=1 width=125) (actual time=0.122..0.122 rows=0 loops=1)
  Output: avl_vehiculo_equipo.imei, cliente_avl_equipo.id_cliente, cliente_avl_vehiculo.grupo, avl_vehiculo.id, avl_vehiculo.id_clase, avl_vehiculo_clase.icono, avl_vehiculo.descripcion, avl_vehiculo.patente, avl_vehiculo.info, avl_vehiculo.conductor, avl_ (...)
  Buffers: shared hit=6
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..22.29 rows=1 width=67) (actual time=0.121..0.121 rows=0 loops=1)
        Output: cliente_avl_vehiculo.grupo, avl_vehiculo.id, avl_vehiculo.id_clase, avl_vehiculo.descripcion, avl_vehiculo.patente, avl_vehiculo.info, avl_vehiculo.conductor, avl_vehiculo.fijo_chasis, avl_vehiculo.enabled, avl_vehiculo_equipo.imei, cliente (...)
        Buffers: shared hit=6
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..14.92 rows=1 width=63) (actual time=0.120..0.120 rows=0 loops=1)
              Output: cliente_avl_vehiculo.grupo, avl_vehiculo.id, avl_vehiculo.id_clase, avl_vehiculo.descripcion, avl_vehiculo.patente, avl_vehiculo.info, avl_vehiculo.conductor, avl_vehiculo.fijo_chasis, avl_vehiculo.enabled, avl_vehiculo_equipo.imei
              Buffers: shared hit=6
              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.00..14.58 rows=1 width=63) (actual time=0.119..0.119 rows=0 loops=1)
                    Output: avl_vehiculo.id, avl_vehiculo.id_clase, avl_vehiculo.descripcion, avl_vehiculo.patente, avl_vehiculo.info, avl_vehiculo.conductor, avl_vehiculo.fijo_chasis, avl_vehiculo.enabled, avl_vehiculo_equipo.imei, avl_vehiculo_equipo.id
                    Buffers: shared hit=6
                    ->  Index Scan using fki_avl_vehiculo_equipo_imei on public.avl_vehiculo_equipo  (cost=0.00..7.28 rows=1 width=12) (actual time=0.118..0.118 rows=0 loops=1)
                          Output: avl_vehiculo_equipo.imei, avl_vehiculo_equipo.id, avl_vehiculo_equipo.movil, avl_vehiculo_equipo.creation, avl_vehiculo_equipo.updated, avl_vehiculo_equipo.power_input, avl_vehiculo_equipo.ign_input, avl_vehiculo_equipo.po (...)
                          Index Cond: (avl_vehiculo_equipo.imei = 1234)
                          Buffers: shared hit=6
                    ->  Index Scan using index_avl_vehiculo_id on public.avl_vehiculo  (cost=0.00..7.29 rows=1 width=51) (never executed)
                          Output: avl_vehiculo.id, avl_vehiculo.id_clase, avl_vehiculo.descripcion, avl_vehiculo.patente, avl_vehiculo.info, avl_vehiculo.numero, avl_vehiculo.conductor, avl_vehiculo.combustible, avl_vehiculo.consumo, avl_vehiculo.marca, av (...)
                          Index Cond: (avl_vehiculo.id = avl_vehiculo_equipo.id)
              ->  Index Scan using index_cliente_avl_vehiculo_id on public.cliente_avl_vehiculo  (cost=0.00..0.33 rows=1 width=8) (never executed)
                    Output: cliente_avl_vehiculo.cliente_rut, cliente_avl_vehiculo.vehiculo_id, cliente_avl_vehiculo.id_cliente, cliente_avl_vehiculo.grupo
                    Index Cond: (cliente_avl_vehiculo.vehiculo_id = avl_vehiculo.id)
        ->  Index Scan using fki_cliente_avl_equipo_imei on public.cliente_avl_equipo  (cost=0.00..7.36 rows=1 width=12) (never executed)
              Output: cliente_avl_equipo.rut_cliente, cliente_avl_equipo.imei_equipo, cliente_avl_equipo.id_cliente
              Index Cond: (cliente_avl_equipo.imei_equipo = 1234)
  ->  Index Scan using index_avl_vehiculo_clase_id on public.avl_vehiculo_clase  (cost=0.00..0.27 rows=1 width=62) (never executed)
        Output: avl_vehiculo_clase.id, avl_vehiculo_clase.descripcion, avl_vehiculo_clase.categoria, avl_vehiculo_clase.icono
        Index Cond: (avl_vehiculo_clase.id = avl_vehiculo.id_clase)
Total runtime: 1.535 ms
```

Comment: Zero rows in less than a millisecond - is this what you expect from the query?

Comment: @deszo and Erwin Brandstetter sample query outputs ZERO rows as just used 1234 for illustration purposes (I have a ? in that part of my query as it a parameter). Actual queries range in the the same amount of time, buy my problem arises fro the fact that this queries are very regularly used, so the problem is not the execution of a single query, but several calls of the same type, do you get what I mean?

Comment: How many if these queries are running?

Comment: @dezso at peak times about 3000 of these queries are exectued sequentially

Comment: but how much time do you have for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use table aliases, explicit JOIN syntax, trim noise and format the code to make it human-readable:

```
SELECT ave.imei
     , cae.id_cliente AS idcliente  -- odd alias?
     , cav.grupo
     , av.id
     , av.id_clase
     , avc.icono
     , av.descripcion
     , av.patente
     , av.info
     , av.conductor
     , av.fijo_chasis
     , av.enabled
FROM   avl_vehiculo_equipo  ave
JOIN   cliente_avl_equipo   cae ON cae.imei_equipo = ave.imei
JOIN   avl_vehiculo         av  ON av.id           = ave.id
JOIN   cliente_avl_vehiculo cav ON cav.vehiculo_id = av.id
JOIN   avl_vehiculo_clase   avc ON avc.id          = av.id_clase
WHERE  ave.imei = 1234;
```

It's now evident that, except for `avl_vehiculo`, you only need *two* columns from each table, probably just `integer` columns (would be ideal).

For top read performance optimized for this query, have this set of indexes:

```
ave(imei, id)                -- index only scan
cae(imei_equipo, id_cliente) -- index only scan
av (id, id_clase)            -- index scan
cav(vehiculo_id, grupo)      -- index only scan
avc(id, icono)               -- index only scan
```

Assuming Postgres 9.2 or later, and if some preconditions are met, you will now get **[index-only scans](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans)** for all except `avl_vehiculo`.

I would `CLUSTER` (or [pg_repack](https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack) if you cannot afford exclusive locks) all involved tables based on these indexes at least once. More:

- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)
- [Index that is not used, yet influences query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/72649/index-that-is-not-used-yet-influences-query/72673#72673)

Sequence of index columns matters!

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field?lq=1)

Comment: Seems a great answer, I'll try to test it during the day, thanks a lot!